# Can't see disk partitions

Tags: partitioning

I replaced windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 16.
My windows was in C drive but Now I cannot see my other disk partitions. I am new to Linux . what should I do ? 
(I didn't dual booted, I replaced windows with Linux).

Comment: If you replaced Windows with Ubuntu, you do not have those partitions you had in Windows any more.